# FPDF variable row height for mysql report

Tags: mysql, report, fpdf

I want to use FPDF for repots from database.

```html
$srg=mysql_query("select * from musteriler order by olusturmatarih"); 
      $sira=0;
      while($m=mysql_fetch_assoc($srg)){ $sira++; 
                
                $pdf->Cell(10,10,$sira,1,0,'L');
                $pdf->Cell(20,10,$m['olusturmatarih'],1,0,'L');
                $pdf->Cell(50,10,mb_convert_encoding($m['adisoyadi'], "ISO-8859-9","UTF-8"),1,0,'L');
                $pdf->Cell(25,10,$m['telefonno'],1,0,'L');
                $pdf->Cell(25,10,'',1,0,'L');
                $pdf->Cell(60,10,$m['adres'],1,0,'L');
                $pdf->Ln();
    
      }
$pdf->Output();
```

here is my code for genarating pdf. But if text in the cell is long text overflows. I tried to use multicell but multicell only chacges one cell height.

Is there any way to set all cells height to same row cells like html tables?

[image: fpdf vs html table]
<sub>(source: [maridarsho.com](https://maridarsho.com/fpdf.png))</sub>

Comment: please try to use ROW. it's more flexible. try this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565847/fpdf-linebreak-in-php/54567783

Comment: You can try to use this link ([FPDF linebreak in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565847/fpdf-linebreak-in-php/54567783)) . Almost same what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF writeHtml is the best solution I have found for this issue.